# creating ssm secure string with cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-parameter-store

since August 2018 AWS CloudFormation supports AWS Systems Manager **Secure String Parameters** in CloudFormation Templates.

I have been searching high and low but wasnt able to find a way to create a ssm-secure-string via Cloudformation like I can do it for simple SSM parameter via

```
Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
Properties: 
  AllowedPattern: String
  Description: String
  Name: String
  Type: String
  Value: String
```

Can someone help me out? Or is there no way to generate the ssm-secure string right now via Cloudformtion?

Merci A

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/82

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per current [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html), it's not supported to create SSM secure string via cloudformation.

> Note
>
> AWS CloudFormation doesn't support the SecureString parameter type.

What introduced in Aug 2018 is the support for SSM Secure String as ***Parameters*** in cloudformation. [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/aws-cloudformation-introduces-dynamic-references-to-support-aws-/)

For the time being, `CustomResource` is the only way, however having raw value in any kind of infra template for secure string is not recommended.

**Updated (Nov 2019):**

As per [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudformation-update-cli-third-party-resource-support-registry/), we can provide 3rd party resource provider for such use cases. `CustomResource` is good but kind of repetitive if you use in multiple stacks. So now I would prefer using this 3rd party resource providers for common use cases like secure SSM. It's farily simple to implement as well.

Comment: merci, I will have a look into the `Custom Resource` technology.

Comment: I believe that in 2021 one can use `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`

Comment: @machin let's not forget $.40 per secret, vs free with standard parameters. costs are important to consider.